# Who is in the Bitcoin Business Alliance?

Tags: business

I have stumbled upon the [Bitcoin Business Alliance](http://bitcoinbusinessalliance.com/), and heard it includes some of the most influential people in the Bitcoin space.

What businesses or individuals are known to be a part of the BBA?

Comment: side-note: if they don't list their members, they must be irrelevant.

Comment: @Lohoris - not necessarily, they might just want to keep their privacy.

Comment: yeah, but... no. If you own a business, do you think you would really care being part of a secret cabal of businessmen no one knows about? It's all about bragging, leave it out and you've got nothing.

Comment: @Lohoris - I actually think you're mistaken. I am in the process of getting an invite, so while I won't be able to divulge members' identities of course, I believe that I will be able to confirm or deny their general caliber.

Comment: @Lohoris: It's more about a mutually beneficial strategic alliance.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz ok it's not only about bragging, I agree now. Still, as long as member list isn't public I fear it won't collect the interest of the potential new members, and stay too far on the shady line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I won't speak about other people, just that I am now a part of BBA myself.

Comment: Remember Grouch Marx: "I don't care to belong to any club that will have me as a member."